# Return Value of Textarea of External Webpage Using PHP & cURL

Tags: php, html, curl

I am trying to submit the form at https://www.igolder.com/PGP/encryption/ and return the results from the "Encrypted Message" textarea using PHP and cURL. I can see the page with the following code but I don't know if it is submitting the form and I don't know how to get the results. Also, yes, =NXwT is meant to be on a separate line in PGP Public Key textarea. Any feedback would be much appreciated! Here is my code below:

```
//create array of data to be posted
$post_data['ctl00$cp$txtPublicKey'] = '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
=NXwT';
$post_data['ctl00$cp$txtMsgToEncrypt'] = 'Test Message';
$post_data['ctl00$cp$btnGeneratePgpKeys'] = 'Encrypt Message';

//traverse array and prepare data for posting (key1=value1)
foreach ( $post_data as $key => $value) {
    $post_items[] = $key . '=' . urlencode($value);
}

//create the final string to be posted using implode()
$post_string = implode('&', $post_items);

//create cURL connection
$ch = curl_init();

// sets the cURL options
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => "https://www.igolder.com/PGP/encryption/",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,   // return web page
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,  // don't return headers
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,   // follow redirects
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,     // stop after 10 redirects
    CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",     // handle compressed
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], // name of client
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,   // set referrer on redirect
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 30,     // time-out on connect
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 30,    // time-out on response
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR      => 'cookie.txt',
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE     => 'cookie.txt',
    CURLOPT_POST           => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $post_string
); 
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

// execute cURL request
$result = curl_exec($ch);

// prints the cURL result
print_r($result);

/******* instead of printing the entire page, I want to just get the value in the textarea  with the name of ctl00$cp$txtEncryptedMessage *******/

//close the connection
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: What does the `print_r` print? How about `print_r($result)` does that contain the HTML you need?

Comment: print_r basically prints the connection information. Sorry, I should have included that. I have done echo or print_r of the result which displays the webpage contents but no indication of the form being submitted. I just want to get the result found in a textarea.

Comment: Would `urlencode($value)` work when you build the POST data string? There's ambiguous characters in there such as e.g. `+` which you need to be careful on how to handle. The remote server would probably expect POST parameters to be urlencoded and will convert that into a space if you don't urlencode. I'm not saying this will solve the issue, but it may be a source of other issues.

Comment: Thanks apokryfos. I added that and I believe the form is submitting; however, my question is how do I return just the results in specific textarea (e.g. ctl00$cp$txtEncryptedMessage) and store them in a PHP variable? All I am able to return is the whole page and this page doesn't even display the results in the textarea.

Comment: The trick is to get the cURL request to bring back the correct result. The correct result in your case would be the whole page that does have the required text in the textarea. Once you manage to get that then you can get the text via a simple regex or HTMLDom parser. You can't request just a portion of a webpage using cURL.

Comment: I have updated the code to make it more streamlined but it has the same functionality. What I would like is to address this comment /******* instead of printing the entire page, I want to just get the value in the textarea  with the name of ctl00$cp$txtEncryptedMessage *******/. Is this possible?

Comment: @apokryfos That makes sense to me. I know that I am capable of getting the text from the textarea if it were to show up but it doesn't return in the  results. Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: I'm fresh out of ideas. Encoding was one. The other is that the remote server may be populating the textarea using JavaScript which would not be executed if you try and get it via cURL. In that case your only hope is to try and use a headless browser to get it (such as e.g. PhantomJS).

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help